# Форматирование текста внутри переменной

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Есть некий код

```
    AGENT=`/usr/sbin/tcpdump -nl -s 0 -A -r $FNAME 2>&1 | strings | grep -i "User-Agent:"`
```

в результате которого получаю переменную с содержимым http://pastebin.com/NHZfxQeW
Далее хочу распарсить всё это, чтоб с помощью `echo` вывести в консоль построчно каждый **user agent** и делаю это:

```
    FORMATTED_AGENT=$(echo "$AGENT"|tr "User-Agent:" "\n"|sort -u)
    for i in $FORMATTED_AGENT; do
      echo $i;
    done
```

т.е. хочу заменить слова **User-Agent:** на служебный символ начала новой строки, но получаю ошибку `tr: неверный порядок границ диапазона «r-A»` . При помощи `sed` так же не получается - всё так же лепится в одну строку но уже в `$FORMATTED_AGENT`

**Вопрос**: Как это правильно делать если одним из условий задачи является **неиспользование** временных файлов (ну типа записать построчно изначально во временный файлик и `cat` прочитать его)?

Смысл в том, чтоб построчно вывести в консоль то, что мы поместили в `$AGENT` но без использования чего-либо (типа временных файлов). Просто я не знаю другого способа кроме замены повторяющегося **User-Agent:** на символ начала строки, но может вы знаете?

Comment: А `sed` что не выходит ? С `tr` то ясно, это не его работа слова менять, он с символами работает

Comment: @Mike да пробовал я!!1адин Не получается, он всё в строку лепит. Я не знаю почему!!1

Comment: А вы после `sed` результат (всю переменную) печатали, что в ней

Comment: в ней вся строка но уже без user agent и без \n пример тут http://ideone.com/xUz5fB

Comment: Между прочим, на счёт `tr` - тоже и с символами. У меня есть переменная $HER="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6," так вот если попытаться заменить `tr`'ом запятую на `\n` - произойдёт то же самое - ни-че-го, он просто вырежет запятую.

Comment: Пока не знаю почему, но если результат не записывать в переменную что бы sort просто вывел свой результат - то все ok. проблема именно при записи в переменную ...

Comment: Да! Бинго! Проблема в переменной! Я это понял ещё очень давно, но допереть не могу что ей в переменной не нравится :( Сорян, просто голова уже болит. А можно Ваш вариант с sort без записи в переменную?

Comment: Ну гугл отлично ответил на "bash перевод строки в переменной" надо сделать `IFS=''` в начале скрипта что бы при записи в переменную переводы кареток не менялись на пробелы

Comment: @Mike Вы гений! Вкатило! Тогда ещё один вопрос, что сказать sed'у, чтоб User-agent регистронезависимым сделать? :)

Comment: `s/User-Agent/\n/gi` т.е. букву i добавляем

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в настройках разделителя полей при внесении в переменную (`IFS`), что бы переводы кареток оказались в переменной `IFS` не должна быть равна переводу каретки, а именно ему она и равна по умолчанию. Но, что бы `for in` читал построчно ему для работы так же нужна `IFS` разделяющая строки. Поэтому делаем так:

```
IFS=''
FORMATTED_AGENT=$(echo $AGENT | sed $"s/User-Agent: /\n/g" | sort -u)
IFS=\n
for i in $FORMATTED_AGENT; do
      echo XXX: $i;
done
```

Если бы не необходимость сортировки я бы вообще предложил использовать `IFS="User-Agent: "`